# Compartir texto a app inventor

Tags: android, app, appinventor

He estado investigando, porque necesito compartir texto a una app creada con app inventor.

No necesito que tenga un botón mi app y que esta pueda compartir, esto ya se como se hace.

Necesito lo contrario (que aparezca por ejemplo mi app en chrome) y al pulsar se me abra la app con lo que se a compartido.

aclaración/ejemplo: estamos en Google Chrome y queremos compartir el enlace desde las opciones. y nos sale: whatsapp, facebook,... pues que aparezca también mi app. y claramente que mi app capture lo que se le envía.

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="appinventor.ai_quique81.cutout" platformBuildVersionCode="22" platformBuildVersionName="5.1.1-1819727">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/ya" android:label="cutout" android:name="com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name=".Screen1" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".YourActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="appinventor.ai_quique81.cutout.Screen2" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hola Enrique y bienvenido a SO en español. No acabo de entender la pregunta, podrías aclararla un poco editando tu pregunta?

Comment: he puesto una aclaración

Answer (score 2):

Para que una aplicación aparezca en la lista de opciones de shared debes utilizar `intent-filter`.

Algunos ejemplos [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11106806/1468942) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23424137/1468942).

A modo resumen, en tu manifest define ([documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)):

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Dentro del `intent-filter` tenemos 3 atributos:

- `action`: En tu caso `SEND` para recibir.
- `category`: Importante que sea `DEFAULT`
- `data android`: Tipo de `data` que recibes, en este caso texto plano. Podría ser `image/*` para aceptar todo tipo de imágenes.

Comment: En la documentación tienes el resto de información que puedas necesitar, si tienes otras dudas concretas coméntamelo y intento adaptar la respuesta.

Comment: si que tengo una pregunta, ¿como puedo poner esto en app inventor?

Comment: Juraría que en appinventor tienes un fichero Manifest (un XML). ¿No está?

Answer (score 1):

Todas las aplicaciones Android tienen  un archivo Manifest, si tu no la haces manualmente, se crea automáticamente, yo no he usado App Inventor para crear apps pero puedes probar lo que propongo.

**Mi propuesta:**

1.- Descarga Apktool, es una aplicación para ingeniería invera a archivos apk's.Puedes hacerlo desde [aquí,](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/)  sigue una serie de pasos para la instalación que son muy sencillos.

2.- Necesitas tener instalado el JDK de Java, descarga desde [aquí.](https://www.java.com/es/download/)

3.- Necesitar tener instalado el SDK de Android, descarga desde [aquí](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

4.- Disponer de framework-res.apk, (lo encuentras en /system/framework/framework-res.apk).

5.- Dispones del apk (En este caso sería tu app de appInventor)

Cuando tengas eso listo, ubícate en el folder del apk y  escribe lo siguiente en la consola para descompilar el apk:

```
apktool d -s nombre_de_tu_app.apk
```

Con esto creas una carpeta con el mismo nombre que tu app, entras a la carpeta y verás un directorio similar a esto:

```
--TuApp
     ---Assets
     ---Original
     ---res
     ---smali
     ---AndroidManifest.xml

. . .
```

Entonces, abres el archivo llamado *AndroidManifest.xml*, el cual tendrá un aspecto similar a esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="appinventor.ai_mletsch80.AppInvActivityStarter">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  . . .

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
           .......
        </activity>
       . . .

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.googlevoice.SMS_RECEIVED" android:permission="com.google.android.apps.googlevoice.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Ahí colocas las líneas de código que te presentan en la otra respuesta:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Después de haber hecho tus cambios solo queda volver a compilar tu app, con lo siguiente:

```
apktool b nombre_de_tu_app
```

**Nota:**

*nombre_de_tu_app* es el nombre de tu app, no debes de colocarle la extensión apk o te marcará error.

**EDICIÓN**

Al final tu archivo *Manifest* debe quedar algo así (Agregando las líneas bajo tu actividad *launcher*):

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
<!-- Aquí por debajo de MAIN y LAUNCHER ya agregas las líneas -->
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
```

Eso sería todo, si deseas aprender y conocer mas sobre la descompilación y recompilación de apks puedes [visitar este sitio(en inglés)](http://www.droidviews.com/tutorial-how-to-decompile-and-recomplie-apk-files/) y [este otro(en español)](http://gnulinuxvagos.es/topic/2113-compila-y-descompila-aplicaciones-con-apktool-windows/)

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta! me a costado un poco compilarlo me faltaba la firma xD. pero no sale en el lista de aplicaciones para compartir. (arriba pongo el código del manifest)

Comment: ¿En que actividad colocaste las líneas del Manifest?

Comment: Eh actualizado mi respuesta con un ejemplo de como pudo haber quedado tu Manifest, agregué todos los tipos de archivo para que no haya pierde... Recuerda que solo es un ejemplo, por eso dice "yourActivity", todo eso va dentro de tu actividad principal, es decir, Mainactivity..

Comment: Revisa mi ejemplo y corrige tu Manifest.